# How to streaming different video camera in same video tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I have list of different video camera attach in my computer when i click on one camera its show me its steaming in video tag then after i click another video camera in list it show me new video tag in streaming but question is i want to display streaming of video in same video which first display

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <title>Video Camera List</title>

      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js" ></script>

      <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        video {
          border:1px solid gray;
        }
      </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      if (!MediaStreamTrack) document.body.innerHTML = '<h1>Incompatible Browser Detected. Try <strong style="color:red;">Chrome Canary</strong> instead.</h1>';

      var videoSources = [];

      MediaStreamTrack.getSources(function(media_sources) {
        console.log(media_sources);
    //  alert('media_sources : '+media_sources);
        media_sources.forEach(function(media_source){
          if (media_source.kind === 'video') {
            videoSources.push(media_source);
          }
        });

        getMediaSource(videoSources);
      });

      var get_and_show_media = function(id) {
        var constraints = {};
        constraints.video = {
          optional: [{ sourceId: id}]
        };

        navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(constraints, function(stream) {
          console.log('webkitGetUserMedia');
          console.log(constraints);
          console.log(stream);

          var mediaElement = document.createElement('video');
          mediaElement.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
          document.body.appendChild(mediaElement);
          mediaElement.controls = true;
          mediaElement.play();

        }, function (e) 
        {
       //   alert('Hii');  
          document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('hr'));
          var strong = document.createElement('strong');
          strong.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(e);
          alert('strong.innerHTML : '+strong.innerHTML);
          document.body.appendChild(strong);
        });
      };

      var getMediaSource = function(media) {
        console.log(media);
        media.forEach(function(media_source) {
          if (!media_source) return;

          if (media_source.kind === 'video') 
          {
            // add buttons for each media item
            var button = $('<input/>', {id: media_source.id, value:media_source.id, type:'submit'});
            $("body").append(button);
            // show video on click
            $(document).on("click", "#"+media_source.id, function(e){
              console.log(e);
              console.log(media_source.id);
              get_and_show_media(media_source.id);
            });
          }
        });
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Never worked with videos, so just a suggestion I suppose, if you got a click handler for the lists of video camera, why not remove the videos already in the page first in that handler using $("video").remove()??

Comment: I want to streaming in same video tag or same id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a total guess, because I don't stream video, but this seems like reasonable jQuery, so change

```
var mediaElement = document.createElement('video');
mediaElement.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
document.body.appendChild(mediaElement);
mediaElement.controls = true;
mediaElement.play();
```

to this

```
var mediaElement = $('video');
if(mediaElement.length ==0) {
    mediaElement = document.createElement('video');
    mediaElement.controls = true;
    mediaElement.autoplay = true;
    mediaElement.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    document.body.appendChild(mediaElement);
} else {
    mediaElement.attr('src', window.URL.createObjectURL(stream));
    mediaElement.attr('autoplay', true);
    mediaElement.load();
}
```

Comment: OK, the code above allows me to switch video streams in Chrome, so if you were correct that it worked before but created multiple windows, now it will keep opening in the same window, after the first one is created